# Custom JSON response if no records are found | PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following PHP script that creates an array JSON response that looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "person": "PER1020",
        "occupation": "Manager",
        "name": "Josh"
    }
]
```

The following is the script itself:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['code']  )) {

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare( ' SELECT 
    `person`,
    `occupation`, 
    `name`
     WHERE 
    `code` = :code ' );

    $stmt->execute([

        'code' => $_POST['code']

    ]);


  $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  echo json_encode($row);

}


?>
```

If nothing is found in the select query how can I make the JSON response:

```
[
    {
        "found": "no"
    }
]
```

UPDATE:

```
 $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($stmt->rowcount() > 0){
      echo json_encode($row);
 }
else {
        echo json_encode($json['found'] = "no"); 
     }
 //echo json_encode([$row]);

}
```

If there are records it writes it correctly, but if there are no records I cannot seem to get it to display:

```
[
    {
        "found": "no"
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `rowCount()` function to check if there are any results or not.

```
if($smtp->rowcount() > 0){
      // if there are results 
     $json['key'] = value ...
 }
else {
            $json = array(
                "found" => "no"
            );  
     }
 echo json_encode([$json]);
```

Comment: How can I specifically have a custom JSON array show as the response?

Comment: What goes in $json['key'] = value ... ?

Comment: If select query return something , u can create json . Its just symbolic

Comment: Can you please show how this can be implemented using the script from my question? I would really appreciate it

Comment: Your example is a bit confusing

Comment: Dont hang on my example. Just, you ca use rowCount() function to learn if your query has at least 1 element or not . If yes do something , if not show json

Comment: Please see my update, I cannot seem to get the last part to work

Comment: Is print something When you echo anything in else statement ?

Comment: Yes else statement does work but I cannot get it in the right format. Can you please have a look?

Comment: You forgot [] . change else statement like  echo json_encode([$json['found'] = "no"]);

Answer (score 1):

In php you can use any variable in the `if` statement. And `$row` fits for the purpose perfectly.

Besides, you should really take out all useless braces from your code

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(!$data){
    $data = ["found" => "no"];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```